# Configure odoo sales

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I need to configure Odoo sales module in such a way like when I sell a product the product must go to a warehouse (To Client) before delivery. Currently when I sell a product a delivery order is created and is delivered to customer location instead of this I need to store the sold products in another warehouse and from there after some process will be delivered.

Can I achieve this process via routing? Is this possible by configuration without any kind of coding??

Answer (score 2):

In warehouse default Configuration Available For Sales / Purchase.

[image]

**You need to just configure 2-steps.odoo will automatically create routes.**